# How to remove yarn workspaces correctly?

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json, yarn-workspaces

I configured 2 workspaces in `package.json` e.g `example` and `gatsby-theme` but later I found I was actually developing a gatsby-starter so I removed the `example` workspace that depended on the latter workspace from `package.json`.

I wonder if I moved all files from `gatsby-theme/` to the project root directory  and overwrote the `package.json` and other files with `gatsby-theme`'s, does it become a project that could be managed with both `npm` and `yarn`?